# What does it mean when my circuit has an indeterminate/no solution?

Tags: ideal

1. I could not solve this with KVL and KCL equations.
2. I did arithmetic until I ended up with a single equation with two unknowns 40 + v1 = v2.
3. I'm going to reread these 2 chapters so maybe I'll understand it my second time around, while now, I would appreciate help.
4. I get the feeling that v1 and v2 may behave with resonant behavior or switch amplitudes interconnectedly as the resonant RLC circuits behave.
5. The solution I come with after this will go up on my YouTube video for these solutions, I hope you can do an awesome job of helping so we can help others.

[image]

Comment: posting a youtube video, does not help others

Comment: Unstoppable force vs immovable object doesn't make sense because it is a case of ideal components arranged in a way to mutually oppose each other without any non-idealities to buffer them from each other. Since they are ideal and opposing, but there are no buffers, there's nothing to give and logical contradictions occur so nothing makes sense. Your circuit is just another case of this.

Comment: @jsotola I post hand-written solutions with notes to help people who haven’t found a way to these solutions (help) yet. I know I’m not able to teach electrical engineering right now.

Comment: @RenzoM-Svartz:  Then post them on a web site where people can read the notes instead of scrubbing through a video, squinting at the notes as they flit by.  Use a website with MathJax to do the equations.  Include written explanations and diagrams that people can scan for information and look at rather than hiding useful information behind the low resolution and slow access of a video.  In other words, if you are going to take the time to make information available then you should do it right and make it accessible.

Comment: @RenzoM-Svartz But you expect thousands of people to read through it and help you. That's a lousy attitude.

Comment: @pipe can’t hear tone through text. you’re being rude unless i’m wrong about your tone. here’s why i think you may be being rude. i don’t expect help, so do you get why you’re being rude? you’re saying i have a lousy attitude. my audience is people looking for answers to see what they should have done. the notes improve the answers to the questions, supplementing the exercises’ topic. i was going to mention this post and link to it. further, i have time available for taking pictures of these exercise and posting them in one youtube video under a title “Solutions to Chapter n Exercises of ...”.

Comment: @pipe I study 5-7 hours everyday, as a goal, and I’m working on the healthiest lifestyle I can have. I’m also starting to see a psychologist and psychiatrist to fix my mental health and I don’t have the time to post these high-quality, and awesome, answer-videos. I imagine I may try to help engineering students in the future in a variety of ways. can you keep you’re posts focused on the engineering and not judge?

Comment: At risk of taking this conversation further off-topic, I have to agree with remarks above (but not necessarily the wording). When you share these videos, your viewers are entrusting you to convey material in suitable depth and with a certain level of accuracy and care. Sharing answers ties right into that; I did my best to go beyond simply sharing an answer with a discussion of the phenomena at play. I think that if you do your best to offer the same to your viewers in high-quality videos, they will be quite appreciative. Simply sharing book solutions just doesn't have the same impact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I did arithmetic until I ended up with a single equation with two unknowns 40 + v1 = v2.

This is precisely the goal of the problem author. They want to show you a problem that can't reasonably be solved when every source is ideal. There's a surprisingly rich set of ramifications from this, which affects real-world simulations that don't look like this contrived circuit.

> I get the feeling that v1 and v2 may behave with resonant behavior or switch amplitudes interconnectedly as the resonant RLC circuits behave.

I won't concern myself with real-world circuits, because you have given a schematic model and we ought to solve it using tools appropriate to schematic models.
Resonant behavior (or amplitude fluctuation) is a product of a real-world circuit. Here, the sources are ideal mathematical models. The problem is purely mathematical, and we would only be able to conclude that we cannot find a full meaningful solution.

For this specific circuit, there is an infinite family of possible solutions, described by the equation 40 + v1 = v2, because there is another degenerate constraint (the currents flowing through the left and center branches happen to exactly sum to 20 mA).

In terms of the language used by circuit simulator error messages, nodes V1 and V2 are said to "float" relative to ground. An analogy would be trying to solve this system of linear equations:

$$ \begin{align}x + y &= 1\\
0 &= 0\end{align}$$

Now suppose that we tweak one current source by a *tiny* amount. This could be a numerical or rounding error in a simulation model, or just by design:

[image: schematic showing an unsatisfiable KCL at one node, due to a 20 mA source entering and two parallel sources of 5.001 mA and 15 mA leaving]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOYfyE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit is still degenerate, but now it has no possible solution. Can you see why?

(I strongly urge you to stop reading here and try to work it out for yourself on paper if it isn't immediately obvious).

In our equation analogy, we are now solving a structure that looks mathematically like:

$$ \begin{align}x + y &= 1\\
0 &= 0.01\end{align}$$

No matter what you do with \$x\$ and \$y\$, there's just no way to make 0 equal to 0.01. Same here. No matter how much you play with voltages, you're not going to be able to fix the fact that 20.001 mA of current enter node V2, while only 20 mA of current leave it.

This is one reason why circuit simulators use slightly non-ideal sources and models. One common option is a Gmin, where a large (i.e. gigaohms or higher) resistor is inserted (automatically by the simulator) in parallel with certain problematic elements:

[image: The same schematic with a 5.001 mA current source, but with a 1 gigaohm resistor in parallel with each current source]

Can you now solve this circuit by hand? You can. The values may be absurd (i.e. kilovolts present at the nodes), but at the very least the model is solvable (in simulator parlance, it is said to converge now)

(Again, I recommend that you stop here, and try to work out the circuit on paper. You don't need to necessarily solve it given the annoying numbers, but convince yourself that it does have a unique, well-defined solution. As a further exercise, take a circuit which *can* be solved and has reasonable values for all its components, add some GMins, and show that the answer is *approximately* equal to that without the GMin terms)

The circuit shown here is a contrived example, since it's always ill-conditioned, but there are real-world circuits that, for one reason or another, end up ill-conditioned like this for brief moments as they settle (this is an artifact of the simulation, and the circuits being simulated never blow up like this in real life). Imagine for instance, a common CMOS inverter (taken from *The Designer's Guide to Spice and Spectre* by Kundert<sup>1</sup>):

[image: An inverter consisting of an NMOS and PMOS element]

You could have a model for the circuit which makes the upper and lower transistors have infinite output impedance (i.e. acting like ideal current sources) in certain conditions. For this answer, we don't really need to concern ourselves with what a transistor is, what its model is composed of, or how it varies in all circumstances. All we care about is that the model breaks down with a floating node (like above), in one particular set of circumstances.

That's not a model that I would ever prefer to use for a variety of reasons, but let's assume that we have this crappy model and are stuck with it. The chart from the same figure shows the issue:

[image: A transfer curve for the inverter showing a region of infinite slope for an intermediate input voltage]

When the input voltage is in the middle, there's a whole family of solutions and the output voltage could be literally anything. Like before, we can throw GMin to make the infinite slope not quite infinite, thus giving us a hope of convergence.

**A side note:** I appreciate the desire to post a Youtube video, but this is a pretty rich topic with a variety of pitfalls and misconceptions, and it's very easy to accidentally say the wrong thing or misinterpret the math, even with the best of intentions.

I strongly suggest that you take the time to really understand the analysis going on, as well as things such as analyzing impedances "seen" by nodes and elements, and so on, before trying to teach this topic to others. You should ideally be deeply familiar with solving real-world circuits, including non-linear ones, to better understand not only the material, but what to emphasize and the pitfalls that may befall you or your viewers.

<sup>1</sup> I highly recommend this book if you're interested in simulation. It discusses various simulation pitfalls and how they are handled by the Spice and Spectre simulation engines. Kundert was affiliated with Cadence Design Systems so he does hint at the benefits of Spectre over Spice quite often, but I am taken to agree with them.

Comment: did you add a link for the book?  I’m not seeing it on mobile

Comment: @relayman357 The book may be [purchased](https://designers-guide.org/analysis/dg-spice/index.html) on Amazon and *excerpts* are available [here](https://designers-guide.org/analysis/dg-spice/index.html) for your preview. There may be other sources of the book which may be able to provide a PDF for free, but I cannot vouch for their safety or legality in your region. The specific figures I use are not available in the excerpt (they come from the second half of the DC analysis chapter)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you don't understand what "indeterminate solution" means.

**I could not solve this with KVL and KCL equations.**

**I did arithmetic until I ended up with a single equation with two unknowns 40 + v1 = v2.**

Yup. And you cannot produce a unique solution for a single equation with two unknowns. That is why any solution is indeterminate.

**I'm going to reread these 2 chapters so maybe I'll understand it my second time around, while now, I would appreciate help.**

Let's try this. Combine the two voltage sources, and combine the two current sources which are in parallel. You should get

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQcLvr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now think about what it means to have an ideal current source. The current is fixed, but the voltage can be anything at all which is consistent across the circuit. So all you know for sure about v1 and v2 is that their difference is 40 volts. That's it. You could have 20 V and -20 V, or 30 and -10, or 157 and 117, or 40 and zero, on any other combination which adds up to the correct total.

There is no way to determine a unique solution - *that's why it's called indeterminate*.

**I get the feeling that v1 and v2 may behave with resonant behavior or switch amplitudes interconnectedly as the resonant RLC circuits behave.**

No. These are ideal sources, and do not need to show any of this sort of behavior. Although they certainly can - you can add AC components to the DC values, and as long as they cancel out, that's another class of possible solutions.